How to sort result based on index name in a query against multiple indices?
I have daily indices named like request_response-yyyy-mm-dd. When I execute the below query
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/request_response-*/_search?stored_fields=value&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": {
        "value": "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c"
      }
    }
  }
}
'

It returns result like below
{
  "took" : 11,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "request_response-2024-05-09",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "value" : [
            "U29tZSBiaW5hcnkgYmxvYg=="
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "request_response-2024-05-10",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "fields" : {
          "value" : [
            "U29tZSBiaW5hcnkgYmxvYg=="
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Can someone let me know if there is a way I can get the hits sorted on the recent index name? I want the document from the recent index to come first.
I can sort the result on the client side after getting the response but here I am asking if it is possible to do it on the OpenSearch side itself?

This is answered in Opensearch forum. The below query will sort the results based on the latest index name
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/request_response-*/_search?stored_fields=value&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": {
        "value": "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_index": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
'

It produces result like below
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "request_response-2024-05-12",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "request_response-2024-05-12"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "request_response-2024-05-09",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "092d882489ea6dc4a6d2dc16d97fb72192b17ca97eaaca59961e97597b6ba80c",
        "_score" : null,
        "sort" : [
          "request_response-2024-05-09"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

